# Why are MsgPack keys of type msgpack_object?

Tags: c, msgpack

In the C API for MsgPack, why are keys (for example the key field of msgpack_object_kv) of type msgpack_object?

https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-c/blob/master/src/msgpack/object.h

Why aren't they just msgpack_object_raw?  Can they be any type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can they be any type?*

Yes. And that's precisely why keys are represented as `msgpack_object`-s.

If you look at the [maps format specification](http://wiki.msgpack.org/display/MSGPACK/Format+specification#Formatspecification-Maps) you can see that maps are defined by `N` = number of pairs within the map where:

> odd elements are key and next element of the key is its associate value

So you are free to use whatever kind of object for keys.

Here's an example (with a map made of 2 pairs) from `test/msgpackc_test.cpp`:

```
unsigned int map_size = 2;
/* ... */
msgpack_pack_map(&pk, map_size);
msgpack_pack_true(&pk);
msgpack_pack_false(&pk);
msgpack_pack_int(&pk, 10);
msgpack_pack_int(&pk, -10);
```

As you can see the first key is a `MSGPACK_OBJECT_BOOLEAN` and the second one is a `MSGPACK_OBJECT_POSITIVE_INTEGER`.